# How to deal with bug in 13.10 that freezes computer when resizing windows?

Tags: unity, compiz

I'm a beginner to ubuntu and there's a [bug in 13.10](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/1244754) than freezes the computer around every 5th time you try to maximize a window by dragging it up against the top of the screen. After this happened, you wouldn't be able to click on anything, although your mouse would move, and you couldn't open terminal and would have to restart your computer. I figured out this fix and thought I'd share.

Comment: in few days you'll be able to update to 14.04, how I know the bug is not present there :)

Comment: What's the output of `apt-cache policy compiz`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open ttyl using

`ctrl, alt and f2`

Type in your name and password and then enter

`unity`

After that, go back to the desktop by holding

`ctrl, alt and f7`

Tada, you restarted unity but didn't crash anything else you were running.